# Can I use in a postgis db within the same table a combination of CRS?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I'm experimenting around with my postgis2.0 database. I want to create a basic table to store all my point data and in the process,I realized that the coordinates are in different CRSs. So naturally I'm wondering now if the  `the_geom` column can contain a variety of CRSs - or Im confined to a single CRS per table.

To visualize it a bit, Is the following possible?

```
point_id | the_geom      |
1        | (geom_string1) <- CRS EPSG:4326
2        | (geom_string2) <- CRS EPSG:2100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not restricted to only having one CRSs per table but it is discouraged.

You also have to have software that can handle showing the geometry in the right location if you mix CRSs

Comment: Hmm thank you for the clarification. So a its considered a good practice to create one table per srid? Are there any special considirations if you want to store points, multipoints, polygoons or other shapes?

Comment: Again, best practises suggest keeping all primitives apart.  If you think of having 10000 points in the same table as 10000 polygons and performing a point in polygons spatial search on it; performence would be an issue, to speak mildly.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually hold two geometry objects in the same row of a table that have different CRS. Again, not actively encouraged, but possible.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    geo geometry(POINT, 4326),
    geom geometry(POINT, 27700)
);

CREATE INDEX foo_geo_gix ON foo USING GIST (geo);
CREATE INDEX foo_geom_gix ON foo USING GIST (geom);

insert into foo (id, geo, geom) values (1, (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-1,52),4326)), (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(200000,570000 ),27700))) ;
```

[image]